# System.ArgumentException: Only Sequence Wires can be snapped

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

I try to open an project on last version of LEGO Mindstorm EV3 Home Edition, but the system shows the next error message 'An unexcpected error has ocurred. Please restart LEGO MINDSTORM EV3.' After that it generate a log with the next error message:

> ================================================================================ ev3-crash-sl-2017-02-25_10-41-11-PM.log
>
> Unhandled exception occurred at 2017-02-25_10-40-43-PM
>   System.ArgumentException: Only Sequence Wires can be snapped.    at
>   NationalInstruments.X3.Model.Wiring.X3WireHelper.IsWireSnapped(Wire
>   wire)    at
>   NationalInstruments.X3.Model.Block.TabletImportHelpers.CleanupTabletImportPrograms(IEnumerable`1
>   vis)    at
>   NationalInstruments.X3.X3VI.Design.MultiProjectSupport.<>c__DisplayClass3f.<>c__DisplayClass43.b__3a()
>   at
>   NationalInstruments.X3.Base.EditorHelpers.PerformActionWhenNoLoadsPending(Project
>   project, Action noLoadsPendingAction, Action projectClosedAction)
>   at
>   NationalInstruments.X3.Base.EditorHelpers.<>c__DisplayClassd.b__a()
>   Stack trace with ILOffsets:    at .X3WireHelper.IsWireSnapped
>   (IL offset: 0xffffffff)    at
>   .TabletImportHelpers.CleanupTabletImportPrograms  (IL offset:
>   0xffffffff)    at .<>c__DisplayClass43.b__3a
>   (IL offset: 0xffffffff)    at
>   .EditorHelpers.PerformActionWhenNoLoadsPending  (IL offset:
>   0xffffffff)    at
>   .<>c__DisplayClassd.b__a 
>   (IL offset: 0xffffffff)
>
> ================================================================================ ev3-log-sl-2017-02-25_10-41-11-PM.log
>
> +000,024 >> MINDSTORMS EV3 launched at 2017-02-25_10-39-52-p.m.
>   +000,024 >> OS Type: Mac
>   +000,024 >> OS Version: Mac OS X 10.12.1 16B2555
>   +000,024 >> Silverlight version: 5.1.50901.0
>   +000,026 >> MINDSTORMS EV3 assembly file version: 1.0.30908.1
>   +000,026 >> MINDSTORMS EV3 build drop: R1-X3-Dev[GC]_20160908.1
>   +000,122 >> In Application_Startup
>   +000,125 >> Starting plugin loading
>   +002,079 >> Starting InitializeNewRespectingForRootCatalog
>   +005,571 >> Starting GetExportedValue()
>   +005,595 >> Starting GetExportedValue()
>   +006,321 >> Generated XmlSerializer for requests/responses/server messages in (seconds): 0,660005
>   +006,358 >> Message queue successfully claimed.
>   +006,382 >> Starting GetExportedValue()
>   +006,388 >> MINDSTORMS EV3 version: 1.2.2
>   +006,388 >> MINDSTORMS EV3 running as: Retail
>   +006,388 >> Starting setup phase 1
>   +006,433 >> MINDSTORMS EV3 language: en-US
>   +006,434 >> Starting setup phase 2
>   +006.448 >> _implicitFallbackString set to ""
>   +006.450 >> Starting setup phase 3
>   +006.855 >> FallbackString is ""
>   +006.857 >> Starting setup phase 4
>   +007.209 >> Generated XmlSerializer for requests/responses/server messages in (seconds): 0.326752
>   +007.845 >> Starting setup phase 5
>   +007.852 >> Starting setup phase 6
>   +007.854 >> Starting setup phase 7
>   +008.059 >> Starting setup phase 8
>   +008.059 >> Starting setup phase 9
>   +008.069 >> Startup done
>   +010.566 >> Time for CreateAndRelinquishX3ProjectInstanceAtLaunch (seconds): 1.346874
>   +012.597 >> Time to load lobby (seconds): 2.027232
>   +012.597 >> Editor load completed
>   +013.536 >> Loading project from "/Users/JoseCoronel/Desktop/WALL-E7_bazmarc/BT_WALL-E71_LEFT.ev3"
>   +017.277 >> Generating XmlSerializer for BlockHelpSupport took (seconds): 0.015914
>   +024,729 >> Time to create XmlSerializer for MEFAndSerializationHelper (seconds): 0,086546
>   +051.091 >> Unhandled exception occurred at 2017-02-25_10-40-43-PM System.ArgumentException: Only Sequence Wires can be snapped.    at
>   NationalInstruments.X3.Model.Wiring.X3WireHelper.IsWireSnapped(Wire
>   wire)    at
>   NationalInstruments.X3.Model.Block.TabletImportHelpers.CleanupTabletImportPrograms(IEnumerable`1
>   vis)    at
>   NationalInstruments.X3.X3VI.Design.MultiProjectSupport.<>c__DisplayClass3f.<>c__DisplayClass43.b__3a()
>   at
>   NationalInstruments.X3.Base.EditorHelpers.PerformActionWhenNoLoadsPending(Project
>   project, Action noLoadsPendingAction, Action projectClosedAction)
>   at
>   NationalInstruments.X3.Base.EditorHelpers.<>c__DisplayClassd.b__a()
>   Stack trace with ILOffsets:    at .X3WireHelper.IsWireSnapped
>   (IL offset: 0xffffffff)    at
>   .TabletImportHelpers.CleanupTabletImportPrograms  (IL offset:
>   0xffffffff)    at .<>c__DisplayClass43.b__3a
>   (IL offset: 0xffffffff)    at
>   .EditorHelpers.PerformActionWhenNoLoadsPending  (IL offset:
>   0xffffffff)    at
>   .<>c__DisplayClassd.b__a 
>   (IL offset: 0xffffffff)
>
> +051.091 >> App exiting (crash)
>
> ================================================================================ ev3-log-wpf-2017-02-25_10-41-11-PM.log
>
> +000,002 >> MINDSTORMS EV3 launched at 2017-02-25_10-39-48-p.m.
>   +000,011 >> OS Type: Mac
>   +000,011 >> OS Version: Mono reports the following but it is inaccurate: Unix 16.1.0.0
>   +000,011 >> OS Bitness: 32-bit
>   +000,011 >> MINDSTORMS EV3 assembly file version and drop cannot be determined on Mac Desktop - see Silverlight log for this info.
>   +000,227 >> Enabling passive scan for TCP;USB
>   +000,340 >> Generated XmlSerializer for server messages in (seconds): 0,088872
>   +000,389 >> Generated XmlSerializers for requests/responses messages in (seconds): 0,044407
>   +010,317 >> Message queue successfully claimed.
>   +016,121 >> AppFullyLoadedEvent received
>   +054,705 >> App trying to exit (crash)
>   +054,710 >> WorkingSet64:                    446,377,984
>   +054,710 >> VirtualMemorySize64:           1,589,334,016
>   +069,046 >> App exiting (crash)

How I can open the project again to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

*.ev3 project files are zip files that contain a bunch of files.

Using a copy of the original project file you might be able to edit the zip file and throw out a file at a time to see if the project file can be opened.

Otherwise, reloading the EV3 software application might be helpful.

None of that is a real solution, but might be worth a try.